# SQL query to find smallest value above which all values in another column satisfy some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table which contains two columns, an int and a boolean. I need to find the minimum value in the int column (a threshold) above which ALL values in the Boolean column are TRUE. How can I construct this query?

For example:

```
level  | detection
-----------------
5      | False
6      | True
7      | False
8      | True
9      | True
10     | True
```

Should return a level of 8 for this particular scenerio.

Comment: There is no such type as a `boolean` in `SQL Server`.  Are you using a `BIT` field? Or is this a `VARCHAR` field with the literal `True` and `False` strings in them?

Comment: VARCHAR. That's hardly the issue here.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect 8 as your result. For all True the minimum is 6

Comment: Level 7 is false. So 6 is not the threshold for all levels above to be qualified true. 8 is because all levels above it to the maximum (10) are also true.

Comment: Please try my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
Declare @Table table (level int,detection varchar(25))
insert into @Table values
(5,'False')
,(6,'True')
,(7,'False')
,(8,'True')
,(9,'True')
,(10,'True')

SELECT min(LEVEL) AS Threshold
FROM @Table
WHERE LEVEL > (
        SELECT max(LEVEL)
        FROM @Table
        WHERE detection = 'False'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way ([online demo](http://rextester.com/BRUGG25514)).

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                Prev = LEAD([detection]) OVER (ORDER BY [level] DESC),
                CumeRowCount = SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY [level] DESC 
                                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
                CumeTrueCount = SUM(CASE WHEN [detection] = 'True' THEN 1 END) OVER 
                                           (ORDER BY [level] DESC 
                                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT TOP 1 [level]
FROM   T
WHERE  CumeRowCount = CumeTrueCount /*All preceding and current rows must be true*/
       AND Prev <> [detection]      /* Next row not true*/
ORDER  BY [level] DESC
```